# Command Pattern: преимущества над простым вызовом методов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Какие преимущества у него над простым вызовом методов?
Undo/Redo, про Light не предлагать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем "Банду четырех":

> Назначение
>
> Инкапсулирует запрос как объект, позволяя тем самым задавать параметры
> клиентов для обработки соответствующих запросов, ставить запросы в очередь
> или протоколировать их, а также поддерживать отмену операций.

ну и далее:

> Используйте паттерн команда, когда хотите:
>
> - параметризовать объекты выполняемым действием
> - определять, ставить в очередь и выполнять запросы в разное время
> - поддержать отмену операций
> - поддержать протоколирование изменений, чтобы их можно было выполнить повторно
> - структурировать систему на основе высокоуровневых операций, построенных из примитивных

*PS. Вообще странно рассматривать преимущества паттернов проектирования в отрыве от задачи. Для одних задач достаточно простого вызова метода, в других (перечисленных выше) удобно инкапсулировать вызов в объект.*